# IndexError: list index existance range python

Tags: python

Here my code, please help me to resolve the error

[image]

Comment: show you code, as text, please

Comment: please post your code in your question, don't just link a screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first condition should be greater or equal because when `pat = 24`, the program it's going to the else and then is trying to access the range in the index 24 but the last index is 23.

```
roue = range(24)
pat = int(input())
if pat >= 24:
    while pat >= 24:
        pat -= 24
else:
    while pat < 0:
        pat += 24
print(roue[pat])
```

Comment: Please stop answering questions that don't contain any content. Doing so removes any incentive for the poster to edit them, which means they have no value to future readers. It's  great to want to help, but the ultimate goal here is to help people in the future as well as this poster.

Comment: This answear is very Important thank you for help Andres 
here another answear :   
nbZones = int(input())
print(nbZones % 24)